# Decomposition of a rectangular sparse matrix

Tags: matrices, matrix-decomposition

All of the matrices in NLP are large sparse matrices (larger than $1M$ in $850K$). I want to decompose such matrices by the fastest method. Which one is the best method for decomposition of a sparse rectangular matrix:  LU or Cholesky?

I mean: what's the best method in theoretical?

Comment: Which software are you using? If it can handle sparse matrices it probably already has a decomposition function that is optimized for sparse matrices.

Comment: I use python for programming. But I need to know the theorical solution.